# Paged UIScrollView not scrolling using Storyboards

Tags: ios, ios7, uiscrollview

I'm trying to build a paged scrollview off of this youtube example:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vLUQz7TeE7w

However, I'm using Storyboards to set up my scrollview and child views, then, in code, I set the appropriate frames in viewDidLoad:

```
//set up scroll view and child views
self.allowanceScrollView.delegate = self;
[self.allowanceScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(3 * self.allowanceScrollView.bounds.size.width, self.allowanceScrollView.bounds.size.height)];

CGRect aFrame = self.allowanceScrollView.bounds;
self.dailyView.frame = aFrame;

aFrame = CGRectOffset(aFrame, self.allowanceScrollView.bounds.size.width, 0);
self.weeklyView.frame = aFrame;

aFrame = CGRectOffset(aFrame, self.allowanceScrollView.bounds.size.width, 0);
self.customView.frame = aFrame;
```

I've also tried manually setting the scrollview delegate, but when the page loads, the scrollview loads with the last view in front (I have them color coded as in the example) and there is no scrolling.

I've tried finding other examples of using paging with a scrollview without success.
Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: worth mentioning I did set the proper outlets for each view.

Edit: screen shot of view hierarchy in storyboard:
[image: view hierarchy]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, always set up UIScrollViews in viewDidAppear. Also, be sure you made your scrollview scrollable (even though by default it is set YES).

For example...

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [super viewDidAppear:YES];

    scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    scrollView.opaque = NO;

    [scrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];

    [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 800)];

    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Comment: That definitely improved things. Thanks. However, my views are showing in reverse.
Here's my output log:

2014-03-25 20:14:55.048 [31071:60b] Daily frame: {{0, 0}, {320, 171}}
2014-03-25 20:14:55.050 [31071:60b] Weekly frame: {{320, 0}, {320, 171}}
2014-03-25 20:14:55.050 [31071:60b] Custom frame: {{640, 0}, {320, 171}}

The log shows their coordinates as being correct, but my "custom" view is showing up first in the scroll position, with the color I set in the storyboard. The other two show as white, as if they're not being loaded or losing their properties?

Comment: Hm, weird. Could I see the code for the "custom view"?

Comment: There's no other code. I just dropped all three views into the scrollview in the storyboard and set their properties there. Then attached them to outlets in my controller. I've attached a pic of the view hierarchy. The top most view showing in the pic is the custom view (view #3), but as you can see, the log shows it gets placed at 640,0, although it shows at 0,0. Thanks for sticking with it :)

Comment: So you aren't creating the uiviews programmatically, correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Well, I changed the order they were in the hierarchy in the storyboard (reversed it) and now my first view ("Daily") shows first, and the other two are blank, so it's very strange indeed. It's like the code setting their frames isn't actually moving them, but just creating the space in the container.

Comment: Try creating and adding the uiviews programmatically to the scrollview.

Comment: Ok, I removed my views from the storyboard and created all views programmatically and that worked perfectly. I added them back and tried init'ing the views I created in the storyboard but that didn't work, either (I know, I'm reaching here).

Comment: I shortened the width of the top view to "peek" under it and sure enough the second view shows underneath, so all views are loading in the first position, ignoring the frame I set in code.

Comment: Not if I use storyboards :( I'm wondering if it's an autolayout issue in iOS 7. Researching that now.

Answer (score 0):

I turned off Auto Layout for that controller in Storyboard and everything worked perfectly. I will give Roecrew the answer to this since he answered the original question, but I wanted to add this here for others.